# Expressing condition of numbers relative to span

Tags: matrices

I'm not quite sure how to approch this problem, and how to convert it to the said form:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0& 2 \\
1 &1& 3\\
0 &1& 1\\
\end{bmatrix}= [a1, a2, a3] $$
Find a condition on numbers $u, v, w$ such that
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        u \\
        v \\
        w \\
        \end{bmatrix}
 ∈ \textrm{span}\{a1, a2, a3\}$$
and express the condition in the form $au + bv + cw = d$.

Any help would be appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You start with the augmented matrix
$$[A | \mathbf{b}]=A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0& 2 & | &u\\
1 &1& 3 & | &v\\
0 &1& 1 & | &w
\end{bmatrix}$$
Now row-reduce and see what conditions on $u,v,w$ will make this a consistent system.

Comment: Ahh I see, guess it was the unknowns that threw me off, cheers!